# Core UI Admin - External sorter icon not shown React js

Tags: reactjs, sorting, admin, core-ui

I am using core UI Admin for my React JS project. The problem is, I want to apply the external sorting, but arrows are not showing on my column except only one column. I have also provided the string data in the columns.
Is there any way to bring sorter icon on every column header and make it clickable for custom sorting.

```
                  <CDataTable
                    items={clientState.data}
                    fields={[
                        { key: ' ', sorter: true, _style: { width: "1%" }  },
                        { key: ‘clientName’, sorter: true, },
                        { key: 'createdBy', sorter: true , },
                       
                    ]}

                    hover
                    sorter={{ external: true }}
                    onSorterValueChange={(e) => {
                        var typeSort = e.asc ? "ASC" : "DESC"
                        alert(typeSort)
                    }}
                    striped
                    clickableRows

                    scopedSlots={{

                        ' ':
                            (item, index) => (
                                <td>
                                    <div className="has-center-v-middle">
                                        <ImageMiniItem imageURL={item.imageURL} />
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            ),
                        ‘clientName':
                            (item, index) => (
                                <td>
                                    {item.name}
                                </td>
                            ),
                        

                        'createdBy':
                            (item, index) => (
                                <td>
                                    {item.createdBy}
                                </td>
                            ),
                      
                            )
                    }}

                />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went for alternative of it, and used simple HTML based tables in it instead, Yes you can of course add html directly into it and apply custom sorting.

```
<table>
<th onClick={(e) => { sortFunc("firstName", e) }}>first Name</th>
...
</table>
```

Though I wanted the core UI to work fine for my case.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

there is only 2 reasons the arrow icon not appear.

1. the key is not equal with the data coming in (don't get confuse with label)
2. not specify the sorter flag in the datatable (i can see you did)

for the first reason above. you need to something like this instead.

```
 name: (item, index) => (<td> {item.name}</td>),
```

and in the fields you can do like this to maintain the label

```
 { key: 'name', label: 'clientName', sorter: true, },
```

for extra:

- no need to specify 'sorter' flag again in the fields, enough the key and name since the default value is already true when add the flag in table.

Comment: I tried that too, it didn't work. It was like a glitch somehow. :(